# My computer suspends even while I am downloading

Tags: troubleshooting, download, suspend

Why doesn't downloading stuff using Limewire count as activity? I keep finding my computer has suspended when I'm downloading.

So what does count then?

Answer (score 2):

Activity in the context of Windows power settings means input from keyboard or pointing devices.  In other words, to be "active", you need to be moving the mouse or pressing keys on the keyboard.

You can always change your power settings to not auto-suspend.